# How Can I Print the Contents of my Tkinter Window to a Printer

Tags: python, tkinter, printing

I made an App to process and display some data in a Tkinter window. I now want to send the contents of the window to a printer for printing on actual paper. However I don't really see any libraries in tkinter or Python to do this. I have to confess I am very new to tkinter and Python.....

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

tkinter is for a graphics user interface and so is all about display. To print data in a tkinter widget you'd have to retrieve that data depending on what the widget is  and put it on the clipboard (can do this in tkinter) or file it (in a separate function) and use a separate printing app to print.

(edited as per comment)

This code does much the same as the `subprocess` module in a minimalist fashion since you have a specific task on Windows. To test it needs a pdf filepath inserted so I've put in an example that brings up notepad just so it can run as it is.

This has an alternative to checking for print status by use of a manual pause. Then Adobe (or any executable that has the appropriate print facility) can be closed automatically. I'd expect the manual pause to be replaced by an automatic timer set for an estimate time for a document to print. Probably need to consider only the time needed to transfer the document into the printing buffer - but that is up to how you want to operate with your system.

```
"""Process to start external executable.

   . default is to let process run until parent pause is complete then process is terminated in parent,
     .. this allows time for a process started im the child like printing to finish.
   . option to wait until process has finished before returning to parent.

(proc.py)
"""
import _winapi as win
from os import waitpid
from sys import exc_info as ei

def startproc(exe,cmd, wait=False):
    try:
        ph, th, pid, tid = win.CreateProcess(exe,cmd,None,None,1,0,None,None,None)
        win.CloseHandle(th)
    except:
        print(ei()[1])
        ph = 0
        return (ph,'error')
    if ph > 0:
        if not wait: 
            return (ph,'process still going')
        else:
            pid, exitstatus = waitpid(ph,0)
            return (0,'process done')

#exe = "C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Acrobat DC\\Acrobat\\Acrobat.exe"
#cmd = "open <pdf filepath>" 
 
exe = "C:\Windows\System32\\notepad.exe"
cmd = None 

print(__doc__)

proc,msg = startproc(exe,cmd)
print(msg)
if 'done' not in msg:           # manual pause for printing
    input('\n-- carry on --\n') # could be automatic timer
                                           
if msg != 'error' and proc != 0:
    if win.GetExitCodeProcess(proc) == win.STILL_ACTIVE:
        win.TerminateProcess(proc,0)
if 'done' not in msg: print('process closed')

#can delete pdf here

input('\n--- finish ---\n')
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciated! So you mean I should get the contents (not the format) from the widgets (may be 20, 30 or more) then somehow reformat them into what I want to see printed out and then write that to a file? Are there any built in  tkinter functions to help me write formatted text to a file?

Comment: Yes to first and not that I know to second question. There might be a third party module somewhere that will do this. https://pypi.org/ is quite a good place to look. tkinter is about display and not filing

Comment: Once you've got your formatted file how you want it then it depends on your operating system how you might code in the printing. Eg Windows has ```startfile(<path>,'print')``` from the Python ```os module```.

Comment: I used Reportlab and created a pdf file which worked fine. I tried the startfile(<path>,'print') you suggested to print the pdf and this also worked fine. But it printed "silently". I need to print but show the print dialog box first so I can eg select double sided printing. But I cant seem to find a way to do this. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: ```startfile``` works as though you have clicked on the file in Windows Explorer. If your file is pdf , eg 'report.pdf,' then ```startfile('report.pdf')``` should bring up a pdf reader like Adobe if you have that on your system - then print as usual through the reader.  ```startfile(<path>,'print')``` actually runs through Windows Notepad before printing on my machine. If you had an html file then that file path would bring up a browser.

Comment: Thanks! That works really well. It brings up Adobe Reader from which I can print using the print dialog box. Adobe Reader stays open after printing. I guess I can live with this but Is there a way after printing to automatically close Adobe Reader, ? I also want to delete the pdf file after printing. Can I just delete after startfile('report.pdf') or would this delete the file while it is still being printed? Thanks again for your great help.

Comment: No there is no way back to your program with ```startfile``` - it starts a completely independent run as you have found. To do what you want I suggest research ```subprocess``` module.

Comment: Would pay to put up a different question if you try out ```subprocess``` and strike a problem with that.

Comment: Have added to answer with code that works like ```subprocess``` minimalistically !

Comment: @KJ absolutely right - can use any number of executables that are fit for purpose.

Comment: @FredBl Instead of checking the print status could put in a pause to wait for printing process to finish. Have edited code in answer to reflect this. Now Adobe can be automatically closed and the pdf can then be deleted so long as timing of pause is correct.

Comment: Just found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rundll32-printui which might be a better alternative yet.